# How to store single value or entire array from fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, associative-array

I am trying to convert my code from mysql to PDO. While I am able to `print_r` the associative array returned by the `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, I am still not able to store any value (or the entire array) from it in a variable. Despite all the errors and warnings I can't figure out where the problem is. Also, the database I am connecting to has been provided in the code sample as well. I have ben at it for several hours but to no avail. :(
The complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htmL>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<?php 
/*
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `last_log_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `last_log_date`) VALUES
(1, 'salman', '123', '2016-02-13');
ALTER TABLE `admin`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`);
ALTER TABLE `admin`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

*/
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);
    $db_hostname = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=store_db", $db_username, $db_password);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error!:". $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
        }
    $res = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='salman' AND password='123' LIMIT 1"); // username='$manager' AND 
    $res->bindParam(':manager', $manager, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $res->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res->execute();
    print_r($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));//DEBUG PURPOSE ONLY: prints "{Array ( [id] => 1 ) }" meaning data has been successfully retrieved
    $arr = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "the id is:[".$arr['id']."]<br>";//DEBUG PURPOSE ONLY: prints "the id is:[]" meaning the value is not stored in the $arr variable
    echo $arr->id;//ERROR: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator\storeadmin\so.php on line 47
    $existCount=$res->rowCount();
    if((int)$existCount==1){
        while($row = $res->fetchObject()){
            $id = $row->id;
            echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";//DEBUG ONLY: shows if the while loop actually works (it does not)
            }
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id; //ERROR:Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator\storeadmin\so.php on line 54
        $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        echo "id:[".$_SESSION["id"]."]user:[".$_SESSION["manager"]."]pass:[".$_SESSION["password"]."]";
    }
    else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php"> Here </a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php //include_once("../header.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-titles">Admin Login</h2>
            </div>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="so.php" class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" size="40" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" size="40" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="button" value="Log In" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</htmL>
```

P.S: I can't get the while loop to run either.

Comment: Does it return your associative array with those: **{ }** ?

Comment: You can not access `id` like this :  `$arr->id`. `$arr` is an array and `id` is key of array. So you need like this : `$arr["id"]`.

Comment: Yes it returns the associative array with those braces: { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a single value you need `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`.

Also, you heed to fix numerous errors in your code and get rid of all the useless stuff, leaving only

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=store_db", $db_username, $db_password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$res = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$res->execute([$manager,$password]);
$id = $res->fetchColumn();
if ($id) {
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
} else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php"> Here </a>';
    exit();
}
```

You may learn how to use PDO properly [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Answer (score 3):

```
print_r($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Fetches the first record

```
$arr = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Tries to fetch the ***next*** record.... but there isn't one, you've already fetched the first with your `print_r($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` statement, so the resultset cursor has moved to the second record, and there isn't a second record, so nothing can be fetched

Comment: Thanks mate, this works perfectly! I just learned something new :)

Comment: well, almost perfectly...  `$existCount=$res->rowCount();` has now started to produce an error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator\storeadmin\so.php on line 47"